# How eliminate JSC_INVALID_FORWARD_DECLARE errors compiling google closure library files?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

Coming back to a project after several years, I am struggling with changes to Google closure compilation. I am using a fresh download of the closure library from github, and these tools:

> java version "1.8.0_152"
>
> Closure compiler Version: v20200830

With the script quoted below, I get seventeen errors like this, all on closure library files (the only ones I am trying for now):

> js/closure-library/closure/goog/net/browsertestchannel.js:20:0:
> ERROR -[JSC_INVALID_FORWARD_DECLARE] Malformed goog.forwardDeclare
> 20| goog.forwardDeclare('goog.net.BrowserChannel');

The script:

> java -jar closure-compiler-v20200830.jar                
> --language_in ECMASCRIPT_NEXT                         
> --language_out ECMASCRIPT5                            
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/debug/**.js      
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/log/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/testing/**.js    
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/testing/events/**.js    
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/testing/ui/**.js    
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/testing/net/**.js    
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/testing/net/rpc/**.js    
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/array/**.js      
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/asserts/**.js    
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/string/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/reflect/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/userAgent/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/dom/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/dom/browserrange/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/dom/animationframe/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/html/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/html/sanitizer/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/structs/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/style/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/Promise/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/events/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/net/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/net/rpc/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/object/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/uri/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/functions/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/async/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/ui/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/Timer/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/json/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/iter/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/math/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/Disposable/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/labs/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/dispose/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/window/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/a11y/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/positioning/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/date/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/spell/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/graphics/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/fx/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/fx/anim/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/color/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/i18n/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/i18n/uChar/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/fx/css3/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/fs/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/fs/url/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/fs/blob/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/memoize/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/pubsub/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/storage/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/storage/mechanism/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/testing/storage/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/testing/fs/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/crypt/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/closure/goog/crypt/hash32/**.js        
> --js js/closure-library/third_party/closure/goog/mochikit/async/deferred.js 
> --compilation_level SIMPLE             
> --warning_level QUIET 
> --formatting PRETTY_PRINT                             
> --checks_only 
> --third_party 
> --js_output_file dist/quickgoog.js

I am guessing that, because these are google closure's own files, I must have some options backwards, but the google is not offering anything on this specific error. Any advice welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your error, and for some reason removing the `third_party` flag allows me to compile Closure Library successfully. I don't think this is correct, and think you should file a bug on the Closure Compiler Github: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues